# Ruby on Rails: How change can I make with this query to save performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new here and today I got into this situation. I've been assigned to this task to exclude all the filtered users with a filter function.
The function is established and I just have to exclude all the filtered users with specific rules.

```
current_personal = user.personal
Personal.joins(:user).merge(User.user_status_active).
    where(gender: current_personal[:gender].
    where.not(id: current_personal.id)
```

this code is just exclude all inactive users and current_user.
All the filtered users is saved in another table called PersonalFiltered
And I have to adjust it to filter that. I came up with

```
current_personal = user.personal
filtered_ids = PersonalFiltered.pluck(:personal_id).append(current_personal.id)
Personal.joins(:user).merge(User.user_status_active).
    where(gender: current_personal[:gender]).
    where.not(id: filtered_ids)
```

This works just fine. But our system is running with almost 300.000 users. And in PersonalFiltered table has over 6500 records. So my leader ask me to change the code to optimize it. I've been looking for a solution for an hour and still have no luck. Could you guys help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a closing parens at `where(gender: current_personal[:gender]).` for starters.

Comment: And if you want performance help then help us by providing the minimum amount of code to provide a runnable example and examples of input and desired output.

Comment: One small adjustment you can make though is to use a subselect at `where.not(id: filtered_ids)` instead of fetching all the ids into memory.

Comment: What the exact relations between `User`, `Personal` and `PersonalFiltered` ?

Comment: Can you please post the generated SQL query

Comment: Also, I think this should be the optimized solution

Comment: Just make sure you have indexed the proper columns like `user_id` inn`Personal` the field you use to distinguish `user_status_active` should be `active` or something

Comment: @DeepakMahakale both generated SQL query and root of the issue are obvious. Solution is obvious too: denormalization through `SQL VIEW` or changing `Personal` table structure + complex index. To make final answer, we have to know exact table relation.

Comment: @max first, missing parens is not the point here, but thanks.
I can't provide you enough code to run because it's too much.
And I've thought about subselect `where.not(id: filtered_ids)` too.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Sorry because I didn't mention about relation. `User has_one Personal` and `Personal has_many PersonalFiltered`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Thank you for saying that. I thought that too. But my leader asked me to find another way, so I'll try my best. Tomorrow at work I'll post the generated SQL query. And I did all the indexes you said.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale these are the generated SQL. It's kinda long


`SELECT personals.* FROM personals INNER JOIN users ON users.id = personals.user_id WHERE users.user_status = 1 AND personals.gender = 1 AND (personals.id NOT IN (3937, 4979, 4178, 612, 670, 4542, 5115, 5246, 5252, 5258, 581, 335, 1))`